# SQL query to overwrite records

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have a Configuration table in which I have 30 records of default configuration. For other configuration I add new records for those setting which are different.
For ex:

```
ConfigurationId     SettingKey          SettingValue
1(default)             A                    2
1(default)             B                    5
1(default)             C                    9
.                      .                    .
.                      .                    .
2                      A                    5
3                      B                    7
```

Here you can see ConfigurationId 1 which is for default settings have all 30 settings.
For other configurations like 2 has setting only for A and 3 has only B

so when I fetch record for Id 2, I want all SettingKey and SEttingValue which are not present in 2 should come from 1 and which exist in 2 will be overwritten
like this

```
ConfigurationId     SettingKey          SettingValue
2                     A                    5
2                     B                    5
2                     C                    9
```

So For 2, all 30 setting should come from 1 which will be overwritten by settings available in 2. in just above SettingKey A has been overwritten by 2. B,C are from 1

Please ask me if I am unclear.

Comment: What is the [linq] tag for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @SeletedConfigurationID int

SELECT Settingkey, SettingValue
FROM
    (
    SELECT SettingKey, SettingValue,
        row_number() over (partition BY SettingKey ORDER BY ConfiurationID DESC) AS rn
    FROM Configuration
    WHERE ConfigurationID = 1
        OR ConfigurationID = @SelectedConfigurationID
    ) AS Settings
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY SettingKey
```

The inner derived query gets the rows from the default configuration (ConfigurationID = 1) and the rows for the selected configuration.  It sets a row number for each setting key where row 1 will be from the selected configuration, if it exists.  Otherwise, the value from the default configuration is used.

The outer query selects only the first row, where the row number is 1.